# compiler error: is private within this context only on gcc9 with c++17

Tags: c++, c++17, travis-ci, gcc9

I test my code using travis. Recently someone added gcc9 to the set of compilers the code gets tested with. While everything compiles fine with gcc8 (both with c++14 and c++17) and gcc-9.1.0 with c++14 it fails with gcc-9.1.0 with c++17 with the following error:

```sh
/usr/include/c++/9/functional: In instantiation of ‘std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(const _Functor&, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::tuple<int>}; _Functor = SQLite::Statement; _Bound_args = {std::tuple<int>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/functional:811:38:   required from ‘typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = SQLite::Statement&; _BoundArgs = {std::tuple<int>}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<SQLite::Statement(std::tuple<int>)>]’
/home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/ExecuteMany.h:84:9:   required from ‘void SQLite::bind_exec(SQLite::Statement&, std::tuple<_Tps ...>&&) [with Types = {int}]’
/home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/ExecuteMany.h:50:14:   required from ‘void SQLite::execute_many(SQLite::Database&, const char*, Arg&&, Types&& ...) [with Arg = std::tuple<int>; Types = {std::tuple<int, const char*>, std::tuple<int, const char*>}]’
/home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/tests/ExecuteMany_test.cpp:35:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/functional:462:59: error: ‘SQLite::Statement::Statement(const SQLite::Statement&)’ is private within this context
  462 |  : _M_f(__f), _M_bound_args(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)
      |                                                           ^
In file included from /home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/Column.h:13,
                 from /home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/Database.h:13,
                 from /home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/tests/ExecuteMany_test.cpp:13:
/home/travis/build/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/Statement.h:696:5: note: declared private here
  696 |     Statement(const Statement&);
```

the code that throws this error is the following:

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Types>
void execute_many(Database& aDatabase, const char* apQuery, Arg&& aArg, Types&&... aParams)
{
    Statement query(aDatabase, apQuery);
    bind_exec(query, std::forward<Arg>(aArg));
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>
    {
        ((void)reset_bind_exec(query, std::forward<Types>(aParams)), 0)...
    };
}

template <typename TupleT>
void reset_bind_exec(Statement& apQuery, TupleT&& aTuple)
{
    apQuery.reset();
    bind_exec(apQuery, std::forward<TupleT>(aTuple));
}

template <typename TupleT>
void bind_exec(Statement& apQuery, TupleT&& aTuple)
{
    bind(apQuery, std::forward<TupleT>(aTuple));
    while (apQuery.executeStep()) {}
}
```

I use the following code for travis CI to use the corresponding compiler

```
matrix:
  include:
    - compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-9
      env:
        - CC=gcc-9
        - CXX=g++-9
        - CXXFLAGS="-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic"

before_install:
  # coveralls test coverage:
  - if [[ "$CXX" == "g++" ]]; then pip install --user cpp-coveralls ; fi

# scripts to run before build
before_script:
  - gcc --version
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DSQLITECPP_USE_GCOV=ON -DSQLITECPP_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DSQLITECPP_BUILD_TESTS=ON ..

# build examples, and run tests (ie make & make test)
script:
  - cmake --build .
  - ctest --verbose --output-on-failure
```

the class Statement has a private copy constructor and assignment operator, but I wonder why this would cause any issue here, because I do not copy the Statement "query". Especially why this problem only occurs with gcc-9.1.0 with c++17 (on my local machine I use gcc-9.1.1 and it compiles without any errors).

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Is `bind_exec` supposed to be using `std::bind` or some other function called `bind`? If it isn't get rid of the `using namespace std` you have somewhere. If it is supposed to be `std::bind` get rid of the `using namespace std` anyway.

Comment: this is a wrapper around the sqlite3 c library. I will have to work on creating a minimal reproducible example later on , since I can't reproduce it myself (the error occurs when building with gcc 9.1.0 with travis CI, but not locally with gcc 9.1.1). (source code is at https://github.com/maxbachmann/SQLiteCpp). The confusing thing is that actually it should not require a copy constructor for the Statement class and even if it would it should fail for example in other versions of gcc aswell. Here is the corresponding travis build: https://travis-ci.org/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp/builds/549915185

Comment: A quick hack on godbolt fails on all versions of clang and gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/Qlya1l, changing `bind` to `SQLite::bind` fixes it, `std::bind` is getting picked up by ADL for some reason rather than `SQLite::bind`

Comment: wow need to try that (do you have a idea why this happens since I do not use namespace std)

Comment: See https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-argument-dependent-lookup-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: wow thank you I was not aware of this issue. So even in namespace you should still always add the scope?

Comment: its better to avoid declaring functions with the same name as standard functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more minimal example is this:

```
#include <functional>

namespace SQLite
{
    struct Statement
    {
        Statement() = default;
        Statement(const Statement&) = delete;
    };
    template<class ...Args>
    void bind( Statement& s, const Args& ... args )
    {        
    }

    template < typename T >
    void test(T&& t)
    {
        Statement s;
        bind( s, std::forward< T >( t ) );
    }    
}

int main() 
{
    std::tuple< int > t;
    SQLite::test( t );
}
```

As one of your arguments is from the `std` namespace Argument Dependant Lookup brings `std::bind` into the list of usable functions. `SQLite::bind` requires a conversion to `const&` before calling so `std::bind` is a better match.

You have a few options to fix this:

1. explicitly call `SQLite::bind`
2. change the name of `bind` to something that isn't in the standard library (this may be the best option as it stops your users from running into the same issue)
3. change `bind`'s arguments from `const Args& ... args` to `Args&& ... args` to remove the conversion